# Error when not using named parameters when calling a function reference

Tags: flutter, function, dart, parentheses, named-parameters

I get the following error:
The argument type 'void Function(String?)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'
when I this in my code:

```
void openNoteBox(String? docID) {}
...
***onPressed: openNoteBox //Error here***
...
onPressed: () => openNoteBox(docID), // it works here
...
```

```
This fixed it:
void openNoteBox({String? docID}) {}
...
***onPressed: openNoteBox, //error is gone here***
...
onPressed: () => openNoteBox(docID: docID),
...
```

but why would the previous one not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code you defined a required positional parameter. To define an optional positional parameter, use this syntax:

```dart
void openNoteBox([String? docID]) {}
```

From the [documentation on optional positional parameters](https://dart.dev/language/functions#optional-positional-parameters):

> Wrapping a set of function parameters in `[]` marks them as optional positional parameters.

In the second code you defined a named parameter, which by default is optional. From the [documentation](https://dart.dev/language/functions#named-parameters):

> Named parameters are optional unless they’re explicitly marked as `required`.

Also note that you can't define both named parameters and optional positional parameters. From the [documentation on parameters](https://dart.dev/language/functions#parameters):

> A function can have any number of *required positional* parameters. These can be followed either by *named* parameters or by *optional* positional parameters (but not both).